# Return min value greater than previous min value in Excel

Tags: excel

I was wondering if anyone could assist in providing a formula (preferably not using VBA as i am not well versed in VBA) to return the min value greater than the previous min value or the smallest value greater than the previous smallest value.

I have a list of vehicles that I need to control the consumption. The vehicle km’s that are entered are totally random in that the km’s are only entered on the days that each specific vehicle fills up with fuel. I need the spreadsheet to return the last reading of that specific vehicle so that I can determine that km’s traveled.

I have tried using a array formula with min to but it returns the min value of the entire list applicable to that vehicle and not the min value greater than that last min.

I would be most appreciative if you could advise of how I can achieve this with an excel formula, preferably not VBA.

I have attached a file with the sample data, please show solution in the file so that I can review to understand.[Sample File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32180757/Consum%20Control.xlsx)

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT IN YOUR QUESTIONS.

Comment: Please put the sample data as text in the Original post using edit, so we do not need to download anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formulas for task like this (assuming the list of your values is in column `A:A`):

```
=SMALL(A:A,2)
```

This will return the 2nd minimum value counting from the bottom. The opposite of this formula is `=LARGE()`.